# javascript doesn't convert special HTML characters

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters

I have a td-element which can contain some HTML code, e.g. `&lt;`.

This is how I call in in JavaScript:

```
tr.find('td.item a').text(item.name);
```

But the output on the web page shows the HTML code (`&lt;`) instead of the actual character (`<`).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this feature, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling jQuery to treat the input as text, not HTML.

If you want it to treat it as HTML, use the `html()` method, not the `text()` method.

Comment: But than JavaScript interpret the HTML code. `&lt;b&gt;` shouldn't make the text bold but shows it as a string `<b>`

Comment: @pinky0x51 no, if you insert `&lt;b&gt;` you should get the string `<b>`.

Comment: then use jQuerys `.text()`-function but use `unescape()` on the string

Comment: @Alnitak: You are right. I don't know what I did wrong it the first test run but now it works!

Comment: @GNi33 — Whatever the data is, it isn't **URL** encoded … and `unescape` is deprecated (because it is broken).

Comment: @Quentin oh, sorry, i think i got something mixed up here. but I didn't know that it's deprecated actually, thanks for pointing this out